# Print/Save as PDF (keeping the CSS layout)

Tags: html, css, pdf, save

When I simply print (like on paper), or save as PDF a page (using the browser built-in tool), the css is completely ignored and I just get ugly lines after lines of the content!!

Is there a way to do this (without having to convert the HTML 2 PDF/image)?

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I've used CSS3 to really format a page in inches so that I can save to a PDF. I use the html <link> tag to specify media="print" and then call print.css that begins with an @media print line and still Safari and Chrome override all my nice formatting, so I, for one, would still like to see an answer to this question. This should be a great way to create nice PDFs without bloated InDesign.

Answer (score 5):

That's probably cause you've got the `media` option specified.

```
<!-- will ignore css on print -->
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<!-- will only use css when printing -->
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />

<!-- will use both -->
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look up Media Types in CSS... set one up for printing and you should be good to go. I've found that [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmedia.shtml) page is really helpful.