# Saving current page as PDF with CSS styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I have this simple code that does save my current page (based on ID that I wish to save), but when it does bring up saving window, I see it as a plain HTML code without styling. Is there a way how to save PDF including all styling from CSS?

```
<script>

function printDiv(divName) {

 var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
 w=window.open();
 w.document.write(printContents);
 w.print();
 w.close();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you already seen [this library](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)?

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820857/print-save-as-pdf-keeping-the-css-layout

Comment: When I add media type to my style sheet, it still ignores it for some reason. I did try with inline HTML inline styling, and than it does see it! Can't figure out where is the issue

Comment: You probably want to use the `@media print {}` media query.  http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/

Answer (score 0):

```
function printDiv(divName) {
var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
w=window.open();
w.document.write('<style type="text/css"> /* your code here */ </style>' + printContents);
w.print();
w.close();
}
```